# opening ROS stacks in qtcreator

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Opening a ROS package in qtcreator is easy thanks to the built in support for CMake projects. However, when working with stacks that contain a large number of packages it would be convenient to be able to open them all at once in qtcreator, so that you can easily jump between source/header files of multiple packages.

I added the following lines to the MY_STACK CMakeLists.txt in an attempt to achieve this:

```
execute_process(COMMAND rosstack contents MY_STACK OUTPUT_VARIABLE MY_STACK_PACKAGES)
set(MY_STACK_PACKAGE_LIST ${MY_STACK_PACKAGES})
string(REPLACE "\n" ";" MY_STACK_PACKAGE_LIST ${MY_STACK_PACKAGES})
foreach(package ${MY_STACK_PACKAGE_LIST})
  execute_process(COMMAND rospack find ${package} OUTPUT_VARIABLE package_path OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  add_subdirectory(${package_path})
endforeach(package)
```

which should add all the packages in MY_STACK as subprojects of MY_STACK. This would probably work if MY_STACK was a 'normal' CMake project. However, when running cmake . in MY_STACK_PATH there are errors like:

```
rospack found package "MY_STACK" at "", but the current directory is "PATH_TO_MY_STACK_PACKAGE_1".
You should double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the correct precedence order.
```

Is there anyway to get around this or will I have to stick to loading all the packages in MY_STACK as separate projects in qtcreator?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39771/opening-ros-stacks-in-qtcreator/) by [klas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2916/klas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not have a work-around for this problem but suggest to make the stack a "Session" in qtcreator. That way you only have to open the packages once and can directly switch back to the Session/stack as required.

---

Originally posted by [robbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1903/robbel/) with karma: 28 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0